# Storing each column of data from a text file into array in C

Tags: arrays, c, text-files

I have a text file name file.txt with 2 columns of number for example,

```
10 1
20 2
30 3
40 4
50 5
```

I want to be able to store the columns of data into an array so that I can use the data somewhere else. Currently, with the code at the bottom :

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, numofProcesses = 0;
    char *token;    

    // reading the textfile
    char *filename = "file.txt";
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: could not open file %s", filename);
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        // reading line by line, max 256 bytes
        const unsigned MAX_LENGTH = 256;
        char SingleLine[MAX_LENGTH];

        while (fgets(SingleLine, MAX_LENGTH, fp))
        {
            // num of Processes = count the number of line
            numofProcesses += 1;

            // print each line out
            // printf("%s", SingleLine);

            // remove trailing new line
            SingleLine[strcspn(SingleLine, "\n")] = 0;

            // print out each number in the text file base on the line
            // Returns first token 
            token = strtok(SingleLine, " ");
            // Keep printing tokens while one of the
            // delimiters present in str[].
            while (token != NULL)
            {
                printf("%s\n", token);
                token = strtok(NULL, " ");
                
            }
        }
            
        // check number of processes    
        printf("\n\nNumber of process = %d", numofProcesses);

        // close the file
        fclose(fp);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I am able to get:

```
10
1
20
2
30
3
40
4
50
5


Number of process = 5
```

However, the output that I want to get is store in 2 different arrays:

```
array a = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
array b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

May I know if there is anyway I can get the arrays separately?
Thanks.

Comment: All you've to do is store those values in two arrays; you may need `atoi()` or `atol()` string to number conversion functions. Easier to use `fscanf()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can do it. I have made some changes in your code (see comments):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h> // For errno

// Either: int main (int argc, const char *argv[])
// Or:     int main(void)

int main(void)
{
    // reading the textfile
    char *filename = "file.txt";
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    // Check for errors.
    // Use perror("") or strerror(errno) for more meaningful error messages
    if (!fp) {
        printf("Error opening \"%s\": %s.\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    // Always declare your variables near where you use them.

    int numofProcesses = 0;

    // reading line by line, max 256 bytes
    const unsigned MAX_LENGTH = 256;
    char SingleLine[MAX_LENGTH];
    
    // The two arrays you wanted
    const int array_size = 256;
    int a1[array_size], a2[array_size];
    
    while (fgets(SingleLine, MAX_LENGTH, fp))
    {
        // Remove trailing new line
        size_t newline_pos = strcspn(SingleLine, "\n"); // But what if \n is not found?
        SingleLine[newline_pos] = 0;
        
        // Parse the line read
        if (sscanf(SingleLine, "%d %d", &a1[numofProcesses], &a2[numofProcesses]) != 2) {
            // Problematic line...
        }
        
        // num of Processes = count the number of line
        numofProcesses += 1;
    }
    
    // close the file as soon as you are done with it.
    fclose(fp);
        
    // check number of processes    
    printf("Number of process = %d\n", numofProcesses);
    
    // Print to see if they match the numbers in file.txt
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < numofProcesses; i++)
        printf("%d %d\n", a1[i], a2[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
Number of process = 5
10 1
20 2
30 3
40 4
50 5
```

Comment: on your comment on `strcspn`, if `'\n'` is not found, the length of the string is returned, which is perfect. I never thought to use `strcspn` in this way, but I will from now on.

Comment: Thank you so much! You gave me a rough idea of how what i wanted can be done and it works!!

Comment: @NewbieMe Consider upvoting the answer if you found it useful.

Comment: It says.. I need 15 rep to upvote.. @Zakk